# How can I convert a JSON file to a LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, json, dictionary, linkedhashmap

I am making a dictionary and I am trying to convert a JSON file of 100 words given by my teacher into a LinkedHashMap. For example:

```
  {
    "word": "scatter",
    "definitions": [
      {
        "definition": "strew or distribute over an area",
        "partOfSpeech": "verb"
      },
      {
        "definition": "the act of scattering",
        "partOfSpeech": "noun"
      },
      {
        "definition": "move away from each other",
        "partOfSpeech": "verb"
      },
      {
        "definition": "cause to separate",
        "partOfSpeech": "verb"
      },
      {
        "definition": "sow by scattering",
        "partOfSpeech": "verb"
      }
    ],
    "synonyms": [
      "spread",
      "sprinkle"
    ],
    "antonyms": []
  },
```

Any way to help build a LinkedHashMap from this json? Thank you!

Comment: Deserialize it using Jackson/GSON

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you provide a code snippet of your solution?
What kind of out put you wanna have? Which difficulties are you facing?